# Best way to compile JavaFX into Android when on Mac?

Tags: android, macos, javafx, gluon

I'm currently working on an already existing Maven project written in JavaFX, and the goal is to make it run on an Android tablet.

From what I have read online it seems like JavaFX Ports (Gluon/GraalVM) is the way to make this happen. Unfortunately Gluon's Documentation states that you need to compile on the same platform as your intended target, i.e. I can only port for Android on Linux.

I both tried compiling in a Desktop VM (Lubuntu 18.04, 64-bit) and a headless VM (Ubuntu 20.04) with VirtualBox 6.1.26. When the VMs runs on 4GB, out of my computers's 8GB, they can't compile due to insufficient memory. Running them on 6GB makes my computer crash since the host can't run the VM anymore.

I'm using:

- Apache Maven 3.8.2
- JDK 11.0.12
- GraalVM 21.2.0

My questions are:

- Is there's a way to, while on Mac, compile and port my project to Android, without using Gluon and GraalVM?
- Is there another way of running Linux on my Mac, without running a VM through a cloud service? (Security reasons)

Any light shone on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Is there another way of running Linux on my Mac, without running a VM through a cloud service? (Security reasons)` i doubt this is valid here

Comment: Another option is GitHub actions, see: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android_github_actions